# The sentence must contain words and numeric characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to get a sentence that has both words and numeric characters.
I tried many sources but still stuck.

My code:

```
eg_str= ['add - James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30', 'add - Alice, Derrick Street']
reg = re.findall(r'([a-z]{3,}[\s][-][\s][A-Z 0-9 a-z ,\-]+)', str(eg_str))
print(reg)
```

Output I get:

```
['add - James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30', 'add - Alice, Derrick Street']
```

Expected output:

```
['add - James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30']
```

Can anyone help me what I'm missing here?

Update:
Example pattern : 'add - James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30 - 1234'. I want to get exactly this pattern from the list of inputs I have. The regex should omit "ad - Alice, Derrick Street" and "add - Alice, Derrick Street - 1314". Is there a possibility to group expression to match the pattern as follows,

1. 3 or more letters #add
2. -   # -
3. Sentence with alphabets and numbers including, -  #James Smith, Flat 7
   118 Black-horse, MA-021-30
4. -  # -
5. 4 or more digits  #1234

Comment: That regex does **not** reflect the requirement _"both words and numeric characters"_. I'd recommend using e.g. https://regex101.com/r/6sj0pc/1 to explore what the pattern means. Also note `[^\S]` ("not non-whitespace") is `\s` (..."whitespace").

Comment: Also you're converting your list into a single string... you look to be wanting to loop over your list and filter which individual elements match...

Comment: What'd be expected if you had just `X10` or `X 10`  as inputs?

Comment: @JonClements I want to get sentences with numbers. I have put them on the list just to show possible inputs.

Comment: What's your definition of a "sentence"?

Comment: @JonClements Maybe I'm underthinking here, but I answered assuming that each list entry would be a "sentence." M

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen similar here... I was thinking it was as long as each element contains a number and a letter - it's valid. (eg: the same lines as your answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may match on the regex pattern:

```regex
[A-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Z]
```

Python script:

```py
eg_str = ['add - James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30', 'add - Alice, Derrick Street']
matches = [x for x in eg_str if re.search(r'[A-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Z]', x, flags=re.I)]
print(matches)  # ['add - James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30']
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you could just access the first item in the list to get the answer you want.

```
print(eg_str[0])
```

If you are trying to apply the regex to each item in the list then you should loop through the list and then apply the correct regex to it.

```
eg_str= ['add - James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30', 'add - Alice, Derrick Street']

temp = []
for item in eg_str: 
    reg = re.findall(r'([A-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Z])', item)
    temp.append(reg)
print(temp)
```

This would return:

```
[['James Smith, Flat 7 118 Black-horse, MA-021-30'], []]
```

You can learn more about regex here:

https://regexr.com/

https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

You can learn more about how to use lists and access elements of a list here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/